# Battery dies after 2 hours in Logitech K750 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, battery, wireless-keyboard, logitech-keyboard

My Logitech K750 keyboard can go from 100% to 0% in low (75 lux) room light in the space of two hours (as reported by the Logitech Solar program).

The first time it happened I tried replacing the ML2032 battery and it worked fine for about six months. However the problem appears to have come back again. It charges just fine, but seems to discharge extremely quickly.

Is this normal? Given that the initial battery replacement solved the problem (albeit temporarily) I’m not sure if the culprit is the keyboard or the battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon closer examination, it turned out that I had been sold a CR2032 battery instead of a ML2032.

According to [this source](https://www.batteryequivalents.com/lithium-cr2032-dl2032-br2032-ml2032-lir2032-lr2032-batteries-equivalents-and-replacements.html), although both the ML2032 and the CR2032 batteries have a nominal voltage of 3.0 volts, the CR2032 quickly drops to 2.7-2.8 volts in real-life applications.

I replaced the battery with an ML2032 and, 7 months later, the keyboard is still working just fine.

Comment: The CR2032 is not rechargeable, whereas the ML2032 is a lithium ion rechargeable.  That's why your keyboard failed.